# MATLAB Simulink: Algebraic Loop Error 'Algebraic state in loop containing __ computed at time 0.0 is Inf or NaN'

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, algebra

I appear to have an algebraic loop in the system below for the signal "ETc_AngVel":
[image: Simulink System]

And get the error:
"Error using HW5_Initialization (line 183)
Algebraic state in algebraic loop containing
'HW5_Task4_V3/3>Driveline model/Divide' computed at time
0.0 is Inf or NaN.  There may be a singularity in the
solution.  If the model is correct, try reducing the step
size (either by reducing the fixed step size or by
tightening the error tolerances)"

I have tried using a delay, initial condition (as seen in picture), and memory block to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Thank you!